# Low contrast for "Author" label in a Discussion when using high contrast dark mode

Tags: bug, status-review, dark-mode, discussions-space, high-contrast-mode

The label that says "Author" in Discussions is very difficult to read in high contrast dark mode.

- The background is light blue. The CSS style uses `var(--blue-300)` which is rgb(126, 184, 241) or #7EB8F1 or hsl(210,80%,72%).
- The text colour is lighter blue. The CSS style uses `var(--blue-600)` which is rgb(223, 237, 251) or #DFEDFB or hsl(210,78%,93%)

[image: Difficult to read label next to a user's profile in Discussions.]